# Unable to login to Wordpress after domain name change

Tags: wordpress, dns

I bought a new domain name from GoDaddy and changed the domain name of blog which was hosted in BlueHost. Now I am unable to login to my blog in Wordpress. With my new domain url, 
newdomain.com/wp-login.php, I reach the page where I need to enter my username and password. Once I enter the details and press Submit it redirects back to my old domain and gives an "This site can't be accessed error" page

Can some one please suggest how I can overcome this problem as I very new to Wordpress.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the following lines in *wp-config.php* file:

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

Just replace values with the URL of your new domain.

If that doesn't work, check [this](http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/wordpress/wordpress-changing-the-site-url-and-home-settings) tutorial on other different ways to fix this issue, among them 
 a detailed step by step guide on how to modify those values in a database (solution already mentioned by Ingo Seidel answer).

Comment: Awesome! The video helped tremendously. Thanks a bunch! I got everything working

Answer (score 1):

You need to change The Domain Name in the WordPress 
Database. Login to your Provider And search for MySQL myadmin. Open
Your Database and find the dataset "siteurl" and change that
Old one to the new